# OpenBSD: Where to seek for the source of programs in the base system?

Tags: openbsd, source, bsd-ports

In OpenBSD, I use `pkg_info -E $(which [cmd])` to be supplied with the name of the package/port to the executable/command `[cmd]`. Having this information I can further look for the source code to the software.

However, there are some utilities that seem to be shipped with the base install of OpenBSD, such as the `netstat` utility.

Where would I go about finding the source code of such programs?

Comment: They're in the `src.tar.gz` archive corresponding to your release (eg. for [6.6](https://mirror.hs-esslingen.de/pub/OpenBSD/6.6/src.tar.gz))). See "Preloading the source tree" [here](https://www.openbsd.org/anoncvs.html) for some instructions; but notice that you do NOT have to put them in `/usr/src`: you can extract whole or part of the archive anywhere you like and build them from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for the OpenBSD base system and the utilities that it contains is available through CVS.  How you fetch the source code is described in the OpenBSD FAQ, under the section [Building OpenBSD from Source](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html#Bld).  It is also described on the page describing anonymous CVS access: https://www.openbsd.org/anoncvs.html

There is a browsable interface to the CVS repository accessible directly from the OpenBSD homepage: https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/ and there is also a GitHub mirror at https://github.com/openbsd

The `netstat` source is available in [src/usr.bin/netstat](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.bin/netstat/).

---

As a general comment about searching packages: Consider installing `pkglocate` from ports. It provides a `pkglocate` utility that allows you to search files from all available ports, just like `locate` would do for local files.